# Python C extensions reading numpy array with negative strides

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy

I've got a function in Python which is reading some file and creating very long numpy array.

```
def readmat(name):
   outp=loadmat(name);
   outp= outp['screen1'];
   outp=outp['data'];
   outp=outp[0,0];
   outp=outp[0];
   return outp;

signal=readmat('nameoffile.mat');
```

now i create another function which is calling another which is written like Pyextension.

Python:

```
def getfrom(vector,positions):
   outp=np.arange(0,dtype=float); #create needed data type
   clib.getfrom(vector,positions,outp);
   return outp;
```

this functions should execute something like this

a=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19];

b=[0,1,10];

c=getfrom(a,b);

and after that c=[10,11,19]

C:

```
static PyObject *py_getfrom(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
 PyArrayObject *vector, *positions, *output;
 int pos_index, i, *length;

 double pos_in_vector;
 if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOO",&vector,&positions,&output))
 return NULL;

 length=&positions->dimensions[0];
 double *work;
 work=(double*)calloc(*length, sizeof(double))

 for (i=0; i<*length; i++)
{
    pos_in_vector=*((positions->data)+i);
    pos_index=pos_in_vector;
    work[i]=*((double *)(vector->data)+pos_index);
 }
 output->dimensions[0]=*length;
 output->data=work;
 return Py_None;
 }
```

The C function should create needed array 'work' and give it to the structure of variable 'outp' and change outp->dimensions[0] to the right value.

Everything works fine but problem is when  data->strides isn't equal to +8 but -8. (it gives python).
to change sign before 'i' doesn't work.

Can any body help me?

Comment: Usually in Python, a negative stride just means that the data is to be read backwards, but I don't know enough numpy to fully answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the stride is always 8, but your pointer arithmetic is wrong. Just use the given stride and everything should just work.

Something like that (untested):

```
for (i=0; i<*length; i++)
{
    pos_in_vector = *(double*)(positions->data + i * positions->strides[0]);
    work[i] = *(double*)(vector->data + (int)pos_in_vector * vector->strides[0]);
}
```